# How can I check the size of a file in a Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file, filesize

I want to have a batch file which checks what the `filesize` is of a file.

If it is bigger than `%somany% kbytes,` it should redirect with GOTO to somewhere else.

Example:

```
[check for filesize]
IF %file% [filesize thing Bigger than] GOTO No
echo Great! Your filesize is smaller than %somany% kbytes.
pause
exit
:no
echo Um... You have a big filesize.
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If the file name is used as a parameter to the batch file, all you need is `%~z1` (1 means first parameter)

If the file name is not a parameter, you can do something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set file="test.cmd"
set maxbytesize=1000

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^< %maxbytesize% bytes
) ELSE (
    echo.File is ^>= %maxbytesize% bytes
)
```

Comment: Can you explain how the "usebackq" option helps?  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with file size, but if I remove it, it stops working

Comment: @JoelFan: Without usebackq, the ' quote means command and not string (Run FOR /? for the details) Another alternative (To better deal with spaces in filenames) is to use: FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ("%file%") DO ...

Comment: Hi @Anders Can you let me know how I can do the same when I have multiple files in a sequence. Like I want to set if my file is less than 2kb then move it to a diff folder?. My result should test each file in the path and validate.

Comment: Side note: you should check if the file exists, before. Otherwise the file size will simply be an empty string... took me a while to notice.

Comment: Never mind... it doesn't even work to write it into a variable for me for an existing file...

Answer (score 27):

I like @Anders answer because the explanation of the %~z1 secret sauce.
However, as pointed out, that only works when the filename is passed as the
first parameter to the batch file.

@Anders worked around this by using `FOR`, which, is a great 1-liner fix to
the problem, but, it's somewhat harder to read.

Instead, we can go back to a simpler answer with %~z1 by using `CALL`.
If you have a filename stored in an environment variable it will become
%1 if you use it as a parameter to a routine in your batch file:

```batch
@echo off
setlocal
set file=test.cmd
set maxbytesize=1000

call :setsize %file%

if %size% lss %maxbytesize% (
    echo File is less than %maxbytesize% bytes
) else (
    echo File is greater than or equal %maxbytesize% bytes
)
goto :eof

:setsize
set size=%~z1
goto :eof
```

I've been curious about J. Bouvrie's concern regarding 32-bit limitations. It appears he is talking about an issue with using `LSS` not on the filesize logic itself. To deal with J. Bouvrie's concern, I've rewritten the solution to use a padded string comparison:

```batch
@echo on
setlocal
set file=test.cmd
set maxbytesize=1000

call :setsize %file%

set checksize=00000000000000000000%size%
set checkmaxbytesize=00000000000000000000%maxbytesize%
if "%checksize:~-20%" lss "%checkmaxbytesize:~-20%" (
    echo File is less than %maxbytesize% bytes
) else (
    echo File is greater than or equal %maxbytesize% bytes
)
goto :eof

:setsize
set size=%~z1
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 11):

`%~z1` expands to the size of the first argument to the batch file. See

```
C:\> call /?
```

and

```
C:\> if /?
```

Simple example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET SIZELIMIT=1000
SET FILESIZE=%~z1

IF %FILESIZE% GTR %SIZELIMIT% Goto No

ECHO Great! Your filesize is smaller than %SIZELIMIT% kbytes.
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF

:No
ECHO Um ... You have a big filesize.
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to use a DOS function.  Feels cleaner to me.

```
SET SIZELIMIT=1000
CALL :FileSize %1 FileSize
IF %FileSize% GTR %SIZELIMIT% Echo Large file

GOTO :EOF

:FileSize
SET %~2=%~z1

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: there's no function and `:eof` in DOS. Those are features of Windows cmd.exe. [They're completely different](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: Except for the nit about not being DOS. This is the cleanest solution. using call :label to get a numbered argument that can be used.

Comment: FYI I inadvertently had SET FileSize=0 at top of my script and this breaks things. Possibly makes an outer scope variable that remains unchanged when "function call" returns. Hope it helps others...

Answer (score 10):

If your `%file%` is an input parameter, you may use `%~zN`, where `N` is the number of the parameter.

E.g. a `test.bat` containing

```
@echo %~z1
```

Will display the size of the first parameter, so if you use "`test myFile.txt`" it will display the size of the corresponding file.

Answer (score 7):

Another example

```
  FOR %I in (file1.txt) do @ECHO %~zI
```

Comment: I think you need `%I` to be `%%I` and `%~zI` to be `%%~zI` for it to work in a batch file

Answer (score 4):

As usual, VBScript is available for you to use.....

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFile = wshArgs(0)
WScript.Echo objFS.GetFile(strFile).Size & " bytes"
```

Save as `filesize.vbs` and enter on the command-line:

```
C:\test>cscript /nologo filesize.vbs file.txt
79 bytes
```

Use a `for` loop (in batch) to get the return result.

Answer (score 4):

After a few "try and test" iterations I've found a way (still not present here) to get size of file in cycle variable (not a command line parameter):

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~zi
)
```

`~z` gets the file size of the file

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution for evaluating file sizes without using VB/perl/etc. and sticking with native windows shell commands:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('dir /-C %temp% ^| find /i "filename.txt"') do (  
    IF %%i GTR 1000000 (  
        echo filename.txt filesize is greater than 1000000  
    ) ELSE (  
        echo filename.txt filesize is less than 1000000  
    )
)
```

Not the cleanest solution, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Create a one line batch file GetFileSize.bat containing

```
GetFileSize=%~z1
```

then call it

```
call GetFileSize  myfile.txt
if (%GetFileSize) == ()     goto No_File
if (%GetFileSize) == (0)    goto No_Data
if (%GetFileSize) GTR 1000  goto Too_Much_Data
rem Etc.
```

You can even create your test file on the fly to eliminate the pesky required file, note the double percent in the echo statement:

```
echo set GetFileSize=%%~z1 > %temp%\GetFileSize.bat
call %temp%\GetFileSize  myfile.txt
if (%GetFileSize) GTR 1000  goto Too_Much_Data
rem etc
```

This latter solution is antispaghetti.  So nice.  However, more disk writes.  Check use count.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this old question looking to see if Windows had something built in.  The ~z thing is something I didn't know about, but not applicable for me.  I ended up with a Perl one-liner:

```
@echo off

set yourfile=output.txt
set maxsize=10000

perl -e "-s $ENV{yourfile} > $ENV{maxsize} ? exit 1 : exit 0"
rem if %errorlevel%. equ 1. goto abort
if errorlevel 1 goto abort

echo OK!
exit /b 0

:abort
echo Bad!
exit /b 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Important to note is the INT32 limit of Batch: 'Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.'

Try the following statements:

```
IF 2147483647 GTR 2147483646 echo A is greater than B (will be TRUE)
IF 2147483648 GTR 2147483647 echo A is greater than B (will be FALSE!)
```

Any number greater than the max INT32 value will BREAK THE SCRIPT! Seeing as filesize is measured in bytes, the scripts will support a maximum filesize of about 255.9999997615814 MB !

Comment: This is incorrect. I created a 5 GB file and was able to read it's file size using %~z1 and it reported 5056590344.

Comment: That's because it is still a string, not converted to a number. Try to do a comparison, or arithmetic with Set /A, and anything to larger than 2 GB will fail.

Comment: When converting NTFS to FAT32 it is important to determine which files are over the 4GB limit. Though Windows explorer allows searching "size:>4GB", I prefer having a text-output of results. Indeed, Windows 10 still has the INT32 CLI and BATCH limit 2^31. With logic: "Show me all files on my F: drive that need addressing:" - `@for /f "tokens=*" %F in ('dir /s /b /a:-d f:\') do @IF %~zF geq 4294967296 ECHO %F >> FindFilesTooLargeForFAT32.txt`. Output is files over 2GB (not 256MB). 2^31 = 32bit = 2,147,483,648 = 2GB (technically GiB gibibyte 1024^3 * 2).

Comment: Work-around is: explorer filtered view (i.e.: size:>4GB), Ctrl+A, Shift r-click, Copy As Path, Paste in Notepad++, TextFX Tools Sort Ascending (since the Copy As Path doesn't mirror order shown in UI).

Comment: We can get around the INT32 issue by doing it as a padded string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two things.

```
filesize.bat 

@echo off
echo %~z1
```

And then what you're actually trying to size up.

Copy a file only if it's larger than zero / copy only a non-zero file

```
for /f %i in ('filesize filesize.bat') do set z=%i
if %z% gtr 0 ( copy filesize.bat noodles.bat )
```

I found this thread and it was *almost* what I needed, I tried a bunch of different things - this was mildly frustrating because robocopy looked to have /min:1 but got ALL bunged up because I wanted to rename the file in transit which made me have to use @#$!! batch script.

Answer (score -5):

Just an idea:

You may get the filesize by running command "dir":

```
>dir thing
```

Then again it returns so many things.

Maybe you can get it from there if you look for it.

But I am not sure.