# file name with Space causing missing operand

Tags: batch-file, operand

Attempting to make a batch to display the filesize of a file.
I have found an (almost) perfect solution in another post ([How can I check the size of a file in a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199645/)) but whenever I enter a filename with a space, I get "missing operand" on the "FOR" line

I have implemented in a batch like this:

```
echo off
set /p title="Enter Film title: " %=%
set sum1=0
set fname="C:\Users\Public\Videos\ripped\%title%.mkv"
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%fname%') DO set size=%%~zA
set /a sum1=%size%/1000000
echo Finished %title%.mkv, Size %sum1%Mb
```

So, for example, [Royals] works, but [True Lies] doesnt.  I've tried several combinations of quote marks etc but cant get it to work. Probably missing something small but can anyone help?
Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A IN ('%fname%') DO set size=%%~zA`

Comment: Thanks, yes that worked. I'd just found another way by removing the usebackq: (FOR %%A IN (%fname%) DO set size=%%~zA) but not sure if that will cause problems so i'll use yours. Thanks alot

Comment: Please accept his answer (the green tick) to show that your problem or question has been answered.

Comment: @Kay Sometimes I don't know what I'm thinking.