# How to check the size of a file in a path with spaces in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, path, filesize, spaces

I found an answer here: [How can I check the size of a file in a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199645/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-windows-batch-script) and it works well if the file path is without spaces but not if it has spaces

Example:

```
set file=C:\Example.txt
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA
```

works but

```
set file=C:\Program Files\Example.txt
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA
```

not, I tried to double quote the path in variable declaration

```
set file="C:\Program Files\Example.txt"
```

and/or in FOR loop file variable

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('"%file%"') DO set size=%%~zA
```

but none works

Answer (score 2):

```
set "file=C:\Program Files\Example.txt"
for %%A in ("%file%") do set "size=%%~zA"
```

There is no need for a `for /f` command (its normal use is to process file contents or strings or the output of command execution), a *basic* `for` command to grab a reference to a file will be enough.