# batch script delete .ost bigger than 50 GB

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch script to delete Outlook .ost files bigger than 50GB. But loops with "for" command makes me crazy :( 
Also try with "forfiles" command but no luky.
Any idea?

Hi Dennis!
Sorry for so delayed check out...
I have tested it with small ost's and works... but... the IF command don't work with large files... up to ~2GB. I tried with a 45GB file.

Check this:

IF 2147483647 GTR 2147483646 echo A is greater than B (will be TRUE)

IF 2147483648 GTR 2147483647 echo A is greater than B (will be FALSE!)

Just like show on:
[How can I check the size of a file in a Windows batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199645/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-windows-batch-script)

I tried transform into GB but not work:

FORFILES /P "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Outlook" /S /M *.ost /C "cmd /c set /a ostsize=@fsize/1073741824 echo @file"

But not work, then found that there is a problem with forfiles command:

FORFILES /P "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Outlook" /S /M *.ost /C "cmd /c echo=@fsize"

Try it with a 45GB file and returns 8052032512 value... :S  I'm stuck!

Comment: Please google before posting and inform us of what you've done already.

Comment: Shame you aren't willing to learn how to use the `for` command; it's exactly what you need for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution: WMIC to rescue!!!!

Do a wmic query and put into a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic datafile where "path='\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\' and Extension='ost' and FileSize>'48318382080'" get Name /value ^| find "="') do set "file=%%f"
```

Answer (score 1):

`if` seems not to be able to interprete such big numbers as strings (see related question [weird results with IF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35769581/2152082)) as one whould think it should.

And because numbers are limited to 32bit Integer, your only option to work with larger numbers is to explicitely force `if` to compare them as strings (by enclosing them with qoutes).

In addition, I added a bunch of zeros in front of them and then limited them to a fixed lenght (because with string comparison, 41 is bigger than 296 (`4` is bigger than `2`), but the string "00041" is smaller than the string "00296" - strings are compared strictly from first to last character)

```
@echo off
set "size1=2147483647"
set "size2=2147483646"
set "null=000000000000000"
set "size1=%null%%size1%"
set "size2=%null%%size2%"
set "size1=%size1:~-15%"
set "size2=%size2:~-15%"
if "%size1%" gtr "%size2%" echo size1 is greater
```

Comment: IF "2147483648" GTR "2147483647" echo A is greater than B (will be FALSE!) -> now works!!! I don't know about quotes!!!

But I can't fix:
FORFILES /P "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Outlook" /S /M *.ost /C "cmd /c echo=@fsize"

If *.ost size is less than 8052032512 works, but if is bigger still showing 8052032512.

Seems that "forfiles" command can't see more thant 8052032512 bytes :S

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to stackOverflow. It is custom at this site to provide code you tried yourself for a problem you can't solve, as this is a site for people to help eachother with code, not a free coding service.

Because this particular problem is easy to solve, this is what you need:

```
@echo off
FORFILES /S /M *.ost /C "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 53687091200 del @file"
```

Comment: Works great!
Just wanna start from scratch... 
I will not do it again, I swear by my mom!

Comment: Except...  That doesn't work as the "if" statement can't evaluate numbers over a signed 32bit size.  So, your code doesn't work at all for finding files over 50gb in size, the max size you can search for is 2147483646.  I found this out via Google and testing my code.