# weird results with IF

Tags: if-statement, cmd

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35767361/2152082) and it's answers, I did some testing.
One answer suggests, the numbers are too big (out of 32bit integer) and they get truncated, but this doesn't explain the results. Also obviously it doesn't compare both sides as strings (as I would have expected). It seems that `if` gets confused and thinks "well, I don't know - give it a TRUE". (Using `neq`, `gtr`, `lss` instead of `equ`, `geq`, `leq` always give FALSE).

The code works as expected, if any of `a` and/or `b` are within the borders of 32bit integer or contain any char out of [0-9].

```
@echo off
set a=333333333333
set b=444444444444
call :compare
set b=222222222222
call :compare
goto :eof

:compare
echo comparing %a% with %b%
if %a% geq %b% (echo a ^>= b) else (echo -)
if %b% geq %a% (echo b ^>= a) else (echo -)
if %a% leq %b% (echo a ^<= b) else (echo -)
if %b% leq %a% (echo b ^<= a) else (echo -)
if %a% equ %b% (echo a  = b) else (echo -)
if %a% == %b% (echo a == b) else (echo -)
```

Is there any logical explanation for this, or is it just something we have to live with without thinking?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Linking back to "this question" doesn't provide the context to make this a stand alone question.

Comment: I'd expect either a string comparison or an errormessage, but **not** _string1 is not equal AND not less AND not greater than string2_ all at the same time (and as it's obviously no number (in the sense, how `cmd` works - that means not a 32bit INT), I'd expect it to be handled as string). `echo on` clearly shows, there is no truncating or conversion happening, so it seems not to be a `cmd` parsing issue, but an issue with `if` itself.  I'd like to understand, what happens and why.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34491952/2152082)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch file IF failure - How can 30000000000000 equal 40000000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116365/windows-batch-file-if-failure-how-can-30000000000000-equal-40000000000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this result can be found in documentation of function [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) which is used first on using the comparison operators `EQU`, `NEQ`, `LSS`, `LEQ`, `GTR`, `GEQ` as explained in my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).

> **Return Value**
>   On success, the function returns the converted integral number as a long int value.
>   If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned (0L).
>   If the value read is out of the range of representable values by a long int, the function returns LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN (defined in [<climits>](http://www.cplusplus.com/climits)), and [errno](http://www.cplusplus.com/errno) is set to ERANGE.

The last sentence is most important here.

It looks like **IF** in `cmd.exe` is coded similar to this C code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char csNo[] =  "no";
    const char csYes[] = "yes";

    char* pcEndValue1;
    char* pcEndValue2;
    int   iExitCode = 2;
    int   iErrorNumber1;
    int   iErrorNumber2;
    int   iStringResult1;
    int   iStringResult2;
    long  lIntegerValue1;
    long  lIntegerValue2;

    if(argc > 2)
    {
        /* Convert the two arguments to 32-bit signed integers. */
        lIntegerValue1 = strtol(argv[1],&pcEndValue1,0);
        iErrorNumber1 = errno;
        lIntegerValue2 = strtol(argv[2],&pcEndValue2,0);
        iErrorNumber2 = errno;

        /* Failed the conversion for any of the two arguments? */
        if(((lIntegerValue1 == 0) && (*pcEndValue1 != '\0')) ||
           ((lIntegerValue2 == 0) && (*pcEndValue2 != '\0')))
        {
            /* Compare case-sensitive the two arguments as strings. */
            iStringResult1 = strcmp(argv[1],argv[2]);
            iStringResult2 = strcmp(argv[2],argv[1]);

            printf("String comparing %s (a) with %s (b):\n\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
            printf("a GEQ b: %s\n",(iStringResult1 >= 0) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("b GEQ a: %s\n",(iStringResult2 >= 0) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("a LEQ b: %s\n",(iStringResult1 <= 0) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("b LEQ a: %s\n",(iStringResult2 <= 0) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("a EQU b: %s\n",(iStringResult2 == 0) ? csYes : csNo);
            iExitCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Compare the values. */
            printf("Value comparing %s/%ld (a) with %s/%ld (b):\n\n",argv[1],lIntegerValue1,argv[2],lIntegerValue2);
            printf("a GEQ b: %s\n",(lIntegerValue1 >= lIntegerValue2) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("b GEQ a: %s\n",(lIntegerValue2 >= lIntegerValue1) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("a LEQ b: %s\n",(lIntegerValue1 <= lIntegerValue2) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("b LEQ a: %s\n",(lIntegerValue2 <= lIntegerValue1) ? csYes : csNo);
            printf("a EQU b: %s\n",(lIntegerValue2 == lIntegerValue1) ? csYes : csNo);
            iExitCode = 0;
        }
        printf("\nError number a: %d ... %s\n",iErrorNumber1,strerror(iErrorNumber1));
        printf("Error number b: %d ... %s\n",iErrorNumber2,strerror(iErrorNumber2));
    }
    return iExitCode;
}
```

Compiling this C code as console application and running the executable with the parameters `333333333333 444444444444` results for example in output:

```
Value comparing 333333333333/2147483647 (a) with 444444444444/2147483647 (b):

a GEQ b: yes
b GEQ a: yes
a LEQ b: yes
b LEQ a: yes
a EQU b: yes

Error number a: 2 ... Output of function out of range (ERANGE)
Error number b: 2 ... Output of function out of range (ERANGE)
```

And running the executable with the parameters `333333333333 222222222222` results for example in output:

```
Value comparing 333333333333/2147483647 (a) with 222222222222/2147483647 (b):

a GEQ b: yes
b GEQ a: yes
a LEQ b: yes
b LEQ a: yes
a EQU b: yes

Error number a: 2 ... Output of function out of range (ERANGE)
Error number b: 2 ... Output of function out of range (ERANGE)
```

**Note:** The error number and the corresponding error string can differ depending on used C compiler respectively standard library.

In both test cases both arguments resulted in a 32-bit signed integer overflow on conversion from string to long int. Therefore `strtol` returned for all four values `LONG_MAX` and set `errno` to `ERANGE`. But the overflow condition is not evaluated by code of **IF** in `cmd.exe`. It is just checked the conversion result and on which character the end pointer points to for both arguments like by the C code above.

In other words **IF** processes on usage of comparison operators `EQU`, `NEQ`, `LSS`, `LEQ`, `GTR`, `GEQ` always an integer comparison as long as conversion from string to integer does not fail for any of the two arguments because of an invalid character in argument strings. An out of range condition is no reason for **IF** not doing an integer comparison.

A string comparison is done only if one of the two argument strings contains an invalid character for an integer.

Comment: Yesss - That's the kind of stuff I was looking for!". So as I was suspecting, the programmer of `if` was a bit lazy...

Answer (score 1):

It is a limit.

```
C:>set /A a=333333333333
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
```

Comment: yes, I'm totally aware of 32Bit integers and their limitation. But my question is not about `set /a` but about `if`. When `if` "detects" a non-(INT32)-number, shouldn't it use string comparison instead? (and yes, I know, putting both sides in quotes _forces_ string comparison, but that's not my question)

Comment: Converting to string comparison on a large number might be a desirable thing. It just doesn't appear to be what `cmd` does. If the code is in danger of having such a large number, why not quote them and move on. Are you thinking about saving a couple of microseconds off of the clock? If so, another language should be chosen.

Comment: `cmd` handles it as a string - if not, there would be syntax or overflow errors. Also `echo on` shows, that it is parsed as is. It's `if` itself, which can't handle it and always gives TRUE with `equ`, `geq` and `leq` and always FALSE with `equ`, `geq` and `leq`. I want to understand why.

Comment: I think there is a chance that `cmd` is -not- handling it as a string. If handling as a number, it is out of range. Doing a comparison operator on two out of range numbers is probably meaningless. I would have expected an error message, but that would have been helpful.

Comment: an out-of-range _number_ should definitively give an error (at parsing stage already - before even giving it to `if`), so I think it's sure to be a string