# Why does evaluation of an arithmetic expression in batch file produce a not expected result?

Tags: batch-file, variables

My batch script is written for measuring how much traffic between two PCs a network can handle. So the script determines the size of a file and send it from one PC to another and count how many times this works. But there is a weird problem on the calculation of total number of successfully transfered bytes. The value of environment variable `asdf3` printed via `echo` after the calculation seems to be inaccurate.

```
echo hat %count% mal geklappt
echo size: %menge% byte
set /a asdf3=%count%*%menge%
echo es wurden %asdf3% byte verschoben
```

The lines above produce this output:

```
hat 58 mal geklappt
size: 30245 byte
es wurden 2722050 byte verschoben
```

It should be 1754210 (58 * 30245) if my math is okay.

The variables are initialized like this:

```
set file="test.odt"
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set /A menge=%%~zA

set /A count=0
:marker
COPY /Y /V %file% \\%name%\Users\public
if 0==%errorlevel% (
    set/Acount=%count%+1
    goto :marker
)
```

Why does evaluation of the simple arithmetic expression in batch file produce `2722050` instead of expected result `1754210`?

Comment: can't reproduce such behaviour, but you need a space in `set /a count=%count%+1`. btw is the same `set /a count=count+1` or better `set /a count+=1`

Comment: This will not work if you have large files as cmd use 32bit only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not use the syntax `set variable="value"`. It is better to use the syntax `set "variable=value"` and reference the environment variable value as is or concatenated with a fixed string or another environment variable reference enclosed in double quotes. Please take also a look on answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains with even more details why it is better to use `set "variable=value"` with first `"` left to variable name.
2. Do not use `for /F` designed for processing a text file line by line, a string or captured output of a command line to just get a property of a file.
3. Do not use `set /A` which results in interpreting the rest of the line as an **arithmetic expression** to just define an environment variable which is always of type string in memory with a value.
4. The loop runs endless as long as copying the file is successful. Is that really wanted?
5. Avoid usage of `%errorlevel%` with command **IF** as there is the syntax `if errorlevel X` for testing if exit code of previous command or application is greater or equal `X` or `if not errorlevel X` for testing if exit code of previous command is lower than `X` which means usually equal `0` as commands and applications do not exist with a negative value.
6. There is a space character missing between `set` and `/A` and one more between `/A` and `count=%count%+1`.
7. The help output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window explains for `set /A` that environment variables can be referenced within an arithmetic expression with just their name without `%` or `!` around as long as the environment variable name does not contain an arithmetic operator, a delimiter like a space or a comma and can't be mistakenly interpreted as integer number.
8. Windows command processor uses 32-bit signed integer arithmetic and so the value range -2147483648 to +2147483647. This means in combination with file size that the value range is limited to 2 GiB before a not handled or reported overflow occurs on evaluation of the arithmetic expression resulting nearly always in unexpected results. For more details see: [weird results with IF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769581/)
9. There is no need to specify on **GOTO** command line the label with colon at beginning except for special label `:EOF`. For details see [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

Here is your code rewritten with no extra code to work around the 32-bit signed integer limitation.

```
set "name=127.0.0.1"
set "file=test.odt"
for %%A in ("%file%") do set "menge=%%~zA"
set "count=0"

:marker
if %count% == 100 goto Output
COPY /Y /V "%file%" "\\%name%\Users\public"
if not errorlevel 1 set /A "count+=1" & goto marker

:Output
echo hat %count% mal geklappt
echo size: %menge% bytes
set /A asdf3=count * menge
echo es wurden %asdf3% bytes verschoben
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

See also [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&`.

Comment: Thanks for the help now the script works and yes the loop is designed to be endless because i want the system to crash just to look at the maximum speed it can provide.