# Issue with "findstr" using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

Below, I wrote some code. It detects if a Micro-SD card is inserted into the computer and if so, it will ask to enter your pin. After you enter the pin, it will look through the card for a text file that contains a list of pins.

```
:start
cls
echo.
echo.
if exist E:\ (
    goto enterPin
) else (
    echo INSERT YOUR CARD
)
timeout 1 >nul
goto start


:enterPin
echo Enter Account Pin: %chip%
set /p pin=": "

:: Finding the specified pin
findstr /m "%pin%" E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt >Nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Pin "%pin%" is valid
    timeout 1 >nul
    goto account
)

if %errorlevel%==1 (
    echo Pin "%pin%" is invalid
    pause
    goto start
)

:account
cls

:: Finds the name of the account owner and continues
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims=/" %%a in ('findstr /I "%pin%/" E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt') do set "user=%%a"  
for /F "tokens=3 delims=/" %%b in ('findstr /I "%pin%/%user%/" E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt') do set "balance=%%b"  
echo.
echo.
echo Welcome, %user%.
echo.
echo ACCOUNT BALANCE: $%balance%
echo.
echo 1=Deposit / 2=Withdraw / 3=Exit / 4=Refresh
choice /c 1234 >nul 
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto deposit
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 goto withdraw
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 exit
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 4 goto account

:deposit
echo.
echo.
set /p add="Money to Deposit: "
set /a moneytoadd=%balance%+%add%
call jrepl "%pin%/%user%/%balance%" "%pin%/%user%/%moneytoadd%" /f E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt /o -
goto account

:withdraw
echo.
echo.
set /p sub="Money to Withdraw: "
set /a moneytosub=%balance%-%sub%
call jrepl "%pin%/%user%/%balance%" "%pin%/%user%/%moneytosub%" /f 
E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt /o -
goto account
endlocal
```

Here's when the issue comes in. A pin consists of 4 numeric characters (ex. 1234), but if there's two pins with the same characters (ex. 123**4**, 65**4**3), it will say the pin is valid. So for example, if I type **4**, it will just look for just the number 4 in the file. And will say the pin is valid. ***Even though,*** just the number 4 is not an existing pin. My guess is that it's a flaw with "findstr". But I'm not sure.

Contents of "CardInfo.txt":

```
1234/Test User/1000
6543/Another Test User/2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use REGEX (using `<StartOfLine><PIN></>`):

```
findstr /m "^%pin%/" E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt >Nul
```

where `^` is "Start of Line".

Answer (score 1):

Here is what exactly does what you want:

```
@echo off
::add your path below
for /f %%a in (file.txt) do (
   call :funch %%a  
)
:funch
set input=%1
set "modifiedinput=%input:~0,4%"
set /p pin=Enter Account Pin:
if %modifiedinput% equ %pin% ( goto authentication_passed) else ( goto authentication_failed)
:authentication_passed
echo auth passed
rem your code
pause >nul
exit
:authentication_failed
echo auth failed
goto funch
```

it will read the input from file and then extract first four characters which in your case is the pin.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the entire batch file to be more fail safe on execution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem endlocal is executed implicitly by cmd.exe on exiting batch file processing.

:Begin
cls
echo(
echo(
if exist E:\ goto enterPin
echo INSERT YOUR CARD
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 >nul
goto Begin

:enterPin
set "pin="
set /p pin="Enter account pin for %chip%: "
if not defined pin goto enterPin
set "pin=%pin:"=%"
if not defined pin goto enterPin
for /F delims^=01234567890^ eol^= %%I in ("%pin%") do goto enterPin

rem Finding the specified pin.
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /M /C:"%pin%/" E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt >Nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Pin "%pin%" is invalid.
    pause
    goto Begin
)

echo Pin "%pin%" is valid.
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 >nul

:account
cls

rem Finds the name of the account owner and continues
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=/" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /C:"%pin%/" E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt') do set "user=%%I" & set "balance=%%J"
echo(
echo(
echo Welcome, %user%.
echo(
echo ACCOUNT BALANCE: $%balance%
echo(
echo 1=Deposit / 2=Withdraw / 3=Exit / 4=Refresh
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /c 1234 >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto account
if errorlevel 4 goto account
if errorlevel 3 exit /B
if errorlevel 2 goto withdraw

:deposit
echo(
echo(
set "add="
set /P "add=Money to deposit: "
set /A moneytoadd=balance + add
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "%pin%/%user%/%balance%" "%pin%/%user%/%moneytoadd%" /L /f E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt /o -
goto account

:withdraw
echo(
echo(
set "sub="
set /P "sub=Money to withdraw: "
set /A moneytosub=balance - sub
call "%dp0jrepl.bat" "%pin%/%user%/%balance%" "%pin%/%user%/%moneytosub%" /L /f E:\Chip\CardInfo.txt /o -
goto account
```

Issues fixed with this code:

1. There is the command **START**. For that reason it is not advisable to use the string `start` as label although it is possible.
2. It is advisable to avoid an **IF** (...) **ELSE** (...) condition if a simple **IF** condition with **GOTO** can be used too.
3. The usage of full qualified file names wherever possible avoids a batch file not running as expected on environment variables `PATH` (too often) or `PATHEXT` (rarely) are corrupted on the user´s machine.
4. A user has the freedom to enter on a prompt done with `set /P` really anything from nothing to something resulting in further processing in a syntax error with an immediate exit of batch file execution on code not being prepared for any user input. For that reason the first `set /P` prompt is improved and validates if the user entered a string consisting only of digits.
5. The usage of **FINDSTR** is done with additional options to find the pin only at beginning of a line case-sensitive with a literal search and the next character must be a slash character.
6. The recommended syntax for **ERRORLEVEL** evaluation is used in the code.
7. The arithmetic expressions are written using the recommended syntax to work even if the user enters nothing or a string which cannot be converted to an integer number at all.
8. The command **EXIT** is used with option `/B` to just exit the processing of the batch file and not the entire command process.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `choice /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `timeout /?`

Useful pages regarding to the improvements on code:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
- [Syntax error in one of two almost-identical batch scripts: ")" cannot be processed syntactically here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [Safe number comparison in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107966/safe-number-comparison-in-windows-batch-file)