# I need to find the smallest number and print the smallest and the others in bat

Tags: batch-file

i neeed to Write a bat file that accepts three parameters. Of these three parameters, find the smallest one, then display all the numbers from 1 to AND the smallest parameter on the screen.
i tried this but it does not work

```
@ECHO OFF
set /a c=%1
set /a b=%2
set /a a=%3

set Smallest=%d%
if %c% lss %Smallest% set Smallest=%c%
if %b% lss %Smallest% set Smallest=%b%
if %a% lss %Smallest% set Smallest=%a%

Echo Smallest number is %Smallest%
pause>nul
```

Comment: `set Smallest=999999999`. `d` is not defined, so `smallest` would be set to *nothing*.

Comment: soo like 
set /a d=%999999999

Comment: Depending upon the way your integers look, you may be able to do it like this: **1.** ```@For /F %%G In ('"(For %%H In (%*) Do @Echo(%%H) | %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /R"') Do @Set "smallest=%%G"```, **2.** ```@Echo(%smallest%```

Comment: ok it did with the way that magoo showed me but how do i do the display part

Comment: `set /a d=%999999999` would likely work - but by failing to fail. The `%9` means the 9th parameter, which is likely to be empty, so `d` would be set to `99999999` that is, 8 `9`s. What do you mean by "all the numbers from 1 to AND" - an example would be good.

Comment: No need to define `%d%`, just change the line `if %c% lss %Smallest% set Smallest=%c%` by the command `set Smallest=%c%`…

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code for this homework which outputs the smallest number and all numbers from `1` to the smallest number if the smallest number is not less than `1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Smallest=%~1"
if not defined Smallest goto OutputHelp
if "%~2" == "" goto OutputHelp

for %%I in (%*) do if %%~I LSS %Smallest% set "Smallest=%%~I"
echo The smallest number is: %Smallest%
echo(
if %Smallest% GEQ 1 (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%Smallest%) do echo %%I
) else (
    for /L %%I in (1,-1,%Smallest%) do echo %%I
)
goto EndBatch

:OutputHelp
echo %~nx0 must be run with at least two integer numbers as arguments.
echo(
echo Example: %~nx0 489 0x2AF 0715
echo(
echo    An integer number beginning with 0x is interpreted hexadecimal.
echo    An integer number beginning with 0 is interpreted as octal number
echo    which cannot contain the digits 8 and 9 to be valid. An invalid
echo    octal number is interpreted with value 0.
echo(
echo    There is not checked if an argument string is a valid string for
echo    a decimal, hexadecimal or octal integer number in the value
echo    range -2147483648 to 2147483647 (32 bit signed integer).

:EndBatch
echo(
pause
endlocal
```

The output of this batch file on running it with the three numbers of the example without the output of all numbers from `1` to smallest number is:

```
The smallest number is: 0715
```

The octal number `0715` is decimal `461` and the hexadecimal number `0x2AF` is decimal `687` which makes the octal number `0715` the smallest number.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

I recommend to read also:

- [Safe number comparison in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111885/3074564)
- [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /A c=%1, b=%2, a=%3
set /A "comp=((a-b)>>31)+1,one=!comp*a+comp*b,comp=((one-c)>>31)+1,Smallest=!comp*one+comp*c"

echo Smallest: %Smallest%
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Smallest%) do echo %%i
```

That is, if **a > b** then `(a-b)` is positive or zero (else, is negative), and `(a-b)>>31` is zero (else, is -1 because `>>` is a *signed shift* of 31 bits) so finally `((a-b)>>31)+1` is one if **a > b** or is zero if **a < b**. In this way, we use this value `comp` to get b, or not this value `!comp!` to get a; and store the lesser of both in `one` variable.

The same method is used to get the lesser of `one` and `c`.

At end, we show all values from 1 to the lesser...

Comment: ok thanks its for a project and i was having a hard time on it because we im new in the bat files programming soo thx

Comment: Ok. If this answer is useful to you, it is customary to select it as Best Answer by checking the green check mark. Thanks!