# Getting integer input in a .cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do you get the user input as a integer?

I have tried this code:

```bash
echo off
set /p input=Give me your name:

Rem here.
set /p /a loops=Number of loops:

for /L %%i in (1,1,%loops%) do (echo %input% )
pause
```

But when I run the batch file it doesn't print me anything, so I guess something is wrong with the `Rem`arked instruction.

To get the user input as string the instruction is `set /p [input]=[message]`, and to set a enviromental variable of integer type the instruction is `set /a [variable]=[value]`.

So I thought to combine these two instructions. Which instruction is the correct instruction to get the user input as integer?

Comment: There is just one type of variables in batch: STRING. There is no INT. (set /a` is the only exception, which *interprets* strings as integers, but even there, both input and output are strictly strings). So technically, combining `/p`and `/a` doesn't make sense, and indeed doesn't set the variable, which makes your `for` loop void. Remove the `/a`.

Comment: `/a` is for performing **a**rithmetic, not interacting with integers.

Comment: I recommend reading my answers on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) and [Safe number comparison in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111885/3074564).

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:again
SET /p "loops=Number of loops: "
SET /a loopsin=0+%loops%
IF "%loopsin%" neq "%loops%" ECHO "%loops%" is invalid&GOTO again
ECHO %loops%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should repeatedly prompt until an integer is entered.

Note the quotes in the `set /p` - allows the prompt to contain a space.

Comment: Mmm... The OP question is how to _"get the user input as integer"_. IMHO, the OP is asking how to _get an integer_ from _user input_, that is, how to **convert** the user input into an integer. I think the [Stephan comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341200/getting-integer-input-in-a-cmd#comment136346805_77341200) is correct: there is no INT variables, just STRINGS.

Comment: I don't think the OP question is about how to _check_ or _confirm_ that the user input _IS_ an integer (there are _not_ integer variables, isn't it?). IMHO, your solution gives the false impression that the `loops` variable is a string (because the `SET /p` command) and that the `loopsin` variable is an integer (because the `SET /a` command), so you basically indicate _the opposite concept_ to what Stephan said. Just my opinion...