# How do I compare my free disk space with a specific number of bytes?

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat script where I need to compare my free disk space with exactly 18GB.
If it's lower or equal than 18GB, it should exit.
If It's greater, it should continue.

```
@echo off

setlocal

set maxSize=19327352832

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir c:\') do (
    set bytesfree=%%a
)

set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%

Echo %bytesfree%
Echo %maxSize%

If %bytesfree% LEQ %maxSize% Echo You'll need to delete some stuff first & pause & exit
If %bytesfree% GTR %maxSize% Echo Everything ready

endlocal && set bytesfree=%bytesfree%
```

I have 5GB free on C:\, so it should say "Everything ready" but it says "You'll need to delete some stuff first" and I don't now what is wrong.

I'm very new to .bat so if I have unecessary code, please correct me.

Comment: 5 is less than 18, isn't it ?

Comment: Numbers are limited to 32 bit. +/- 2 gig.

Comment: @Mark Really? Is there a way around to fix this?

Comment: Scale it in your head. Work in Megabytes.

Comment: Can you please also clarify how many bytes you've determined are representative of 18GB, _`19327352832` bytes = `18` Gibibytes (GiB) and `18000000000` bytes = `18` Gigabytes (GB)_.

Comment: @Marged: sadly, for `cmd` it's not. (well, 5 *is*  less than 18, but it's different with 5000000000 and 18000000000)

Comment: When CMD was first written 20 Megabytes was big.

Comment: @Stephan I was referring to `I have 5GB free on C:\ so it should say "Everything ready" ` which contradicts `If it's lower or equal than 18GB, it should exit`

Comment: Agreed @Marged, the OP's requirements were "If it's lower or equal than 18GB, it should exit", so as they "have 5GB free on C:", it should **not** say "Everything ready", and is technically providing the correct response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that numbers in batch are limited to INT32 (that's about 2GB), so `if` returns [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769581/weird-results-with-if). As a workaround you can compare the numbers as strings (you need to make sure, they have the same number of digits). Note `dir`'s switch `/-c`, which suprresses the thousand separators:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "maxSize=0000019327352832"
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c c:\') do (
    set bytesfree=0000000000000000%%a
)
set bytesfree=%bytesfree:~-16%
Echo %bytesfree%
Echo %maxSize%

If "%bytesfree%" LEQ "%maxSize%" Echo You'll need to delete some stuff first & pause & exit
If "%bytesfree%" GTR "%maxSize%" Echo Everything ready

endlocal && set bytesfree=%bytesfree%
```

As an alternative, you could use the help of a "proper" programming language (like Powershell) for the math, but that's always slower and not really necessary here (as you can see)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) based [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) would work for you:

```bat
@("%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='C:' And FreeSpace>'18000000000'" Get FreeSpace /Value 2>NUL|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" "=">NUL&&(Echo Everything ready)||(Echo You'll need to delete some stuff first&"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak>NUL&Exit /B))&Pause
```

Change `18000000000` to `19327352832` as necessary.

Comment: Generally, I also prefer a method to get the desired information directly (`wmic` here) over parsing the output of a generic command (`dir` here), but in this case, `wmic` is incredibly slow (compared to the `dir` approach). Interesting though, that `wmic` isn't affected by the INT32 limit.

Comment: Well, 'slow' for me @Stephan, _unless the computer is constantly moving files on and off the system drive_, is not how I'd term a result within a second or two, _which in my experience, this is_.