# How to convert all large PNG files in a directory tree to JPEG files with ignoring the PNG files with less than 10 MB?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

There should be processed with a batch file just files of type *Portable Network Graphics* with the file extension `.png` in the entire directory tree of the current directory which have a file size of greater or equal 10240000 bytes while PNG files with a smaller file size should be ignored for conversion to a JPEG file with *ImageMagick*.

The processing of the batch file below exits on the **IF** condition with following error message on no PNG file found at all:

```
( was unexpected at this time.
```

Existing PNG files are not correct processed according to their file size and I don't know the reason.

```
@echo off
FOR /R %%A IN (*.png) DO (
   SET maxbytes=10240000
   SET size=%%~zF
)

if %size% LSS %maxbytes% (
"G:\00OSz\12win10b zEnt-LTSC 1809 x64\05Apps\Multimedia\Pictures\Installed\png (PNGs)\Support\ImageMagick Win64 static at 16 bits-per-pixel component (portable)\bin\convert.exe" "%%~A" -resize 12%% "%%~dpna.jpg"
    if exist "%%~dpna.jpg" del /Q "%%~a"
)
REM del "zzzPNG to JPG.bat"
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

**10 MB** are 100% correct 10<sup>7</sup> = 10000000 bytes. Most computer programs and users interpret **10 MB** as **10 MiB** which is 10 × 2<sup>20</sup> bytes = 10485760 bytes.

The comparison operator `LSS` tries always converting first the two strings left and right this operator to 32-bit signed integers and on success runs an integer comparison. The value range of 32-bit signed integer is −2<sup>31</sup> to +2<sup>31</sup>−1 which is −2147483648 to +2147483647.

A file size cannot be less than 0 bytes. The negative value range does not matter for that reason. The positive value range could be interesting here if any PNG file has 2 GiB or more bytes. However, the batch file below works also for PNG files with a file size ≥ 2 GiB due to a quirk of `cmd.exe` on comparing integer values not fitting into the 32-bit signed integer range value as described in detail by [weird results with IF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601468/3074564).

The main mistake is running first a **FOR** loop searching recursively in the current directory for files of which long or short file name is matched by the wildcard pattern `*.png` and does for each found file:

1. Define respectively redefine the environment variable `maxbytes` with the string value `10240000`.
2. Define respectively redefine the environment variable `size` with the string value `%~zF` because of the loop variable is `A` and not `F`.

Both commands do not make sense.

The environment variable `maxbytes` needs to be defined with the maximum files size string only once above the **FOR** loop. In fact the environment variable `maxbytes` does not need to be defined at all because of its value is used only on one command line in entire batch file. It is enough to write the bytes string value directly as second operand of the **IF** condition.

The second command line inside the **FOR** loop results assigning always the same string `%~F` to the environment variable size because of the loop variable is `A` and not `F`. However, the usage of `%%~fA` would not make the code better as that would just result in having finally the file size of the last PNG assigned to the environment variable `size`.

The two environment variables `maxbytes` and `size` are not defined by the code in the batch file if there is no PNG file found at all in the current directory and all its subdirectories. If the two environment variables are not defined outside of the batch file, the **IF** condition becomes `if  LSS  (` which is clearly a serious syntax error causing an immediate exit of batch file processing as it can be seen on [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

The comparison operator `LSS` is also wrong here. The condition is **IF** file `size < 10240000` **THEN** which is the opposite of the wanted behavior for converting PNG files of file size `≥ 10 MB` to a JPEG file.

The loop variable references `%%~A` and `%%~dpna.jpg` are other syntax errors. The entire **IF** condition is outside the **FOR** loop. It is not possible to reference a loop variable in a command line which is not in body of a **FOR** loop.

Last the command **EXIT** at end of a batch file makes nearly never sense. It is in most cases just counterproductive, especially on developing and testing a batch by running it from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file in *Windows File Explorer*.

The batch file code should be as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.png /A-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do if %%~zI GEQ 10485760 (
    "G:\00OSz\12win10b zEnt-LTSC 1809 x64\05Apps\Multimedia\Pictures\Installed\png (PNGs)\Support\ImageMagick Win64 static at 16 bits-per-pixel component (portable)\bin\convert.exe" "%%I" -resize 12%% "%%~dpnI.jpg"
    if exist "%%~dpnI.jpg" del /A "%%I"
)
endlocal
```

It is most likely better to evaluate the exit code of `convert.ext` to found out if the conversion from PNG to JPEG was successful and delete the PNG file in this case.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.png /A-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do if %%~zI GEQ 10485760 (
    "G:\00OSz\12win10b zEnt-LTSC 1809 x64\05Apps\Multimedia\Pictures\Installed\png (PNGs)\Support\ImageMagick Win64 static at 16 bits-per-pixel component (portable)\bin\convert.exe" "%%I" -resize 12%% "%%~dpnI.jpg"
    if not errorlevel 1 del /A "%%I"
)
endlocal
```

It would be possible to condense the batch code to a single command line on working with the Windows defaults for command extensions and delayed variable expansion.

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.png /A-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do @if %%~zI GEQ 10485760 "G:\00OSz\12win10b zEnt-LTSC 1809 x64\05Apps\Multimedia\Pictures\Installed\png (PNGs)\Support\ImageMagick Win64 static at 16 bits-per-pixel component (portable)\bin\convert.exe" "%%I" -resize 12%% "%%~dpnI.jpg" && del /A "%%I"
```

[Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) explains the conditional command operator `&&` which executes the next command `del` only on previous `convert.exe` exited with value `0` indicating a successful execution without an error.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line inside `'` appended as additional arguments.